# Compiling/linking GSL

Tags: compiler-construction, linker

I have the following Makefile for a program that uses gsl:

```
CXX = g++
ARCH = -mtune=generic
COFLAGS = $(ARCH) -O3 -pipe -I./gsl
CXXFLAGS = -Wall $(COFLAGS)

PROGRAMS = myProgram
GSLFLAGS= -L./gsl/.libs -lgsl -L./gsl/cblas/.libs -lgslcblas -lm

all: $(PROGRAMS)
myProgram:  myProgram.cpp common.o 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(GSLFLAGS) myProgram.cpp common.o -o myProgram
common.o: common.cpp common.h

common.o: common.h common.cpp 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(BOOSTFLAGS) $(GSLFLAGS) -c common.cpp
```

I get the following output during compilation/linking:

```
g++: -lgsl: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

Any idea what's wrong?

P.S. - I'm aware that the -c flag is involved in it but removing it cause other problems.

Comment: "I'm aware that the -c flag is involved in it but removing it cause other problems." -- of course it does. You should remove `$(GSLFLAGS)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

> I get the following output during compilation/linking

No, you don't. You get this warning during *compilation*, and it tells you *exactly* what the problem is: you are passing `-lgsl` and `-c` together on command line, and `-lgsl` is ignored when you are *not* doing linking (which is what `-c` asks `g++` to do).

Now, your `Makefile` doesn't have a separate `-c` anywhere, so it's somewhat likely you didn't cut/paste your entire `Makefile`, and omitted exactly the details that are relevant here.

**Update**: this is the line where you don't want `$(GSLFLAGS)`:

```
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(BOOSTFLAGS) $(GSLFLAGS) -c common.cpp
```

Finally, this link line:

```
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(GSLFLAGS) myProgram.cpp common.o -o myProgram
```

is wrong: the order of sources/objects and libraries on command line [matters](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html). Correct link line should be:

```
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) myProgram.cpp common.o -o myProgram $(GSLFLAGS)
```

Comment: Ordering in the linking process is always tricky. Thanks for the reminder, solved lots of problems.